# Удаление маршрута Android Google Maps

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

Есть приложение для отслеживания маршрута в реальном времени. При нажатии на кнопку "Старт" начинает рисоваться линия данным кодом:

```
 PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();

    options.addAll(points);
    options.width(6);
    options.color(Color.RED);
    mMap.addPolyline(options);
```

Так вот, нажимаешь на кнопку стоп и карта очищается. После, когда заново нажимаешь на старт старая линия появляется и продолжается. Как удалить старый маршрут  с карты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы не обнуляете массив с координатами.

Нужно обнулять список с points, когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку стоп.